# How to return a Boolean Value inside if else condition to a function in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift

I have problem with returning a boolean value in swift. Initially i created a function(statusAssign) that passing the value to the another constructor(isLoggedIn). Now, this constructor return the gated value from statusAssign function. so, How can i do this?. my coding is below but it seems error.

```
func statusAssign()
{
    let state = "1"

    isLoggedIn(state)
}

internal func isLoggedIn(status:String) -> Bool
{
    var gc:Bool

    if status == "1"
    {
        gc = true
    }
    else
    {
       gc = false
    }

return gc  //Error 1:  return is Nil while wrapping an optional value
}

func usage()
{
    if isLoggedIn() == true  //Error2: Missing Argument for Parameter #1 in call
    {
        print("Buddy is true")
    }
    else
    {
        print("Buddy is false")
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `usage` function, you aren't passing the required string argument

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, because i want to know , how to use a constructor that get value from one function and return a value to another one function. is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "constructor"?

Comment: @Paulw11 oops. actually I don't know. I mentioned `internal func isLoggedIn(status:String) -> Bool
{ return true }` as constructor. sorry i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1:

```
var gc:Bool //This is NOT declared, you just THINK it is
var gc:Bool = false //correct way, also makes it where you DON'T need the else i.e. less code.
if status == "1"
{
    gc = true
}
```

Error 2:

You declare the function `isLoggedIn(status:String)` as a function with a parameter. So when you call `isLoggedIn(status:String)` it requires input. You cannot do `if isLoggedIn()` without a parameter.
I think there is a much easier way to do this, if I am correct. Let me know if this works for you.

```
var isLoggedIn:Bool = false

func logIn() {
    isLoggedIn = true
}
func usage() {
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        print("Buddy is true")
    }
    else
    {
    print("Buddy is false")   
    }
}
```

Apply:

```
logIn()
usage()
```

Comment: Wow Great man!!! Your answer is little confused and had error. but I manipulate your answer to get correct output. but i don't know how to user a constructor that return a value for usage...thanks a lot.. :) :)

Comment: actually it prints false. so i returned the value on function logIn as `func logIn() ->Bool { isLoggedIn = true return isLoggedIn } . then is used if login() == true { //do some } else {//do some}` it is on below

Comment: Ahh! I was thinking you could use like `logIn()` then`usage()`.